# Can't get bike valve caps off

Tags: tire, maintenance, valves

I will sound a bit thick but i'm no bike mechanic, to give you an idea of what make my bike is here are some pics (the bike isn't mine and the owner doesn't know).

[image]
[image]
[image]

the problem is that I cannot get the valve caps off I tried twisting and pulling, pliers are a no no due to the bike not being mine, here's a pic, any help is appreciated, Thanks.

[image]

Quick edit
Just to clarify I've not stolen the bike, 
I crashed mine and it's the beginning of summer and I really wanted to ride, the bike is my mother's and just needs some maintenance. Also I appreciate the answers I've tried using more force but the entire valve seems to turn and jam, no movement on the cap. Any ideas?

Comment: I gather you want to deflate this guy's tires, and you're asking us to assist.

Comment: BTW, this valve cap is no different from the ones commonly used on automobiles.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I think you've misunderstood. The asker is just saying that neither they nor the bike's owner know what the make of the bike is.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - So they didn't notice "Raleigh" written there on the down tube?

Comment: @DanielRHicks Is "Raleigh" the maker and "---trum" the model or is it the other way around? You and I know the answer to that but the asker and owner don't because they know nothing about bikes. It seems, both grammatically and semantically, much more likely that "and the owner doesn't know" refers back to the most recently mentioned "knowable" fact (the brand of the bike) than that it refers to the owner's awareness of the asker's proposed actions.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - What I find most confusing is that neither person has ever seen an ordinary car tire.

Comment: @DanielRHicks \*shrug\* I've never owned a car and I don't think I've ever witnessed anyone inflate a car tyre. Also, it's possible that the asker asked the owner the irrelevant question "What's the make of your bike?" rather than "How do I get the valve caps off your bike?" Anyway, I think we're getting deep into over-analysis here.

Comment: I think "the owner doesn't know" refers to _how to get the dust caps off_.

Comment: If the bike's been left for a while, could be road grime has "glued" the valve cap down.  Since they're plastic caps it won't be rust.  I've occasionally had to use some pliers to turn a valve cap because I have weak hands.  Hold the valve stem between one finger/thumb and unscrew the cap with the other hand or with some pliers for a better grip.

Comment: That's a bog-standard Schrader valve.  Unless the valve is disassembling itself (rare, and only on heavily used wheels) one should be able to simply turn the cap in a counter-clockwise direction and it will come loose.  Sometimes they are a bit sticky, such that a pair of pliers is needed, but the pliers cause little damage so long as you squeeze tight enough that they don't slip.  But after you get the cap off what will you do?  What kind of pump do you have?

Answer (score 3):

Turn anti-clockwise as seen from above and use more force. You should be able to get them off by hand.

If you do destroy the caps, go to a bike store and buy replacements. Ask for 'Schrader' type caps.

<s>Can we assume you are borrowing a bike and need to inflate the tire? The statement 'the bike isn't mine and the owner doesn't know' is slightly troubling. If you have trouble with a borrowed bike take it back to the owner.</s> (deleted as based on misunderstanding.)

Brand and model of bike does not matter, tube valves are either 'Schrader' (same as on car tires) or narrower 'Presta' types.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood. The asker is just saying that neither they nor the owner knows the make of the bike.

Comment: @DavidRicherby ahhh, right. I kinda assume everyone knows what brand and model their bike is.

Answer (score 2):

I think its a cheap tube with minimal/no reinforcement around the bottom of the valve stem.

When you turn the cap the whole valve stem is rotating, and its winding up the tube like a drill-bit into cloth.

So turn the cap in one hand while holding the valve-stem still with the other hand.  You may need one or even two pairs of pliers to get enough grip.

Good luck!

This is what your tube is doing on the inside of the tyre/rim:

[image: https://5.imimg.com/data5/DX/VE/MY-3341757/cotton-drill-fabric-250x250.jpg]